# While loop with small Thread.Sleep vs. Java Timer?

Tags: java, multithreading, timer

I have a program that needs to execute a process at a very precise time. The way I have currently approached it is:

```
while( ( exTime - System.currentTimeMillis() ) > randomNum )
{
    try
    {
        Thread.sleep(0, 5000); //Sleep for 5000 nanoseconds, or 0.000005 seconds
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
//Code to be executed after time is over.
```

I know it is also possible to use a Java timer for this.

My question is what is the most efficient, and what is most accurate? I am running over 100 threads with the while-loop. Will using a timer save more resources and be more accurate?

Comment: How precise is "very precise" here? Bear in mind that `System.currentTimeMillis` may well only have a precision of around 15ms. It seems pointless to try to sleep in 5000ns increments...

Comment: As precise as possible really. IS it possible to be precise to 0ms and some ns instead?

Comment: Not with `System.currentTimeMillis`. If you're trying to measure *relative* time, you should use `System.nanoTime` instead.

Comment: Alright thanks. What about comparing the while loop with the Timer?

Comment: I suspect the timer will have far lower resolution. But why not test it for yourself?

Answer (score 0):

Using a Timer will be accurate. For resources you can check